# Golang split strings by char type

Tags: regex, go

I want to be able to split the string into substrings where characters and numbers are separate groups:

```
re:=regexp.MustCompile("**MAGIC HERE**")
fmt.Println(re.FindAllString("abc123def", -1))
```

I want to be able to get

```
[abc 123 def]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Wiktor this is not exactly duplicate. Even if I know the other post, I would love to know how to do this in Golang.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try splitting on this pattern:

```
\d+|\D+
```

**Code:**

```
re:=regexp.MustCompile("\\d+|\\D+")
fmt.Println(re.FindAllString("abc123def", -1))
```

**Output:**

```
[abc 123 def]
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester